# forward declaring with inheritance information

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, radix, derived

This compiles fine, although I wouldn't want to try running it just yet. However ...

```
//class base;
//class derived;
//class derived : public base;

class base {};
class derived : public base {};

class other
{
    public:
        void func() {base1 = derived1;}
        base* base1;
        derived* derived1;
};

void main()
{
}
```

... moving the class other to above the definition of base and derived for which there is a similar thing I must do in a program of myne causes compile errors.

The obvious solution is to forward declare base and derived shown commented out at the top of the code, however this causes a can't convert between base* and derived* error. Attempting to forward declare including the inheritance information dosn't work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work. You need to move other up

BUT declare func below. That way func is able to "see" that derived is of type base.

e.g.,

```
class base;
class derived;
//class derived : public base;

class other
{
    public:
        void func();
        base* base1;
        derived* derived1;
};

class base {};
class derived : public base {};

void other::func() { base1 = derived1; }
```

Comment: Excellent. Worked well, in this and in the program with the real problem. I'm hoping that this will be the end of the problem for good.

Answer (score 4):

There is no syntax for forward-declaring two classes and specifying that one inherits from the other. This is because inheritance can be complex (multiple and/or virtual), so the assignment `base1 = derived1` might involve some arithmetic, and it's difficult/impossible for the compiler to generate that arithmetic when it only knows that `derived` inherits from `base`.

So, to solve your problem, you can make `func` not inline (see the answer from **AbstractDissonance**), or, if you absolutely need it to be inline, use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
class base;
class derived;

class other
{
    public:
        void func() {base1 = reinterpret_cast<base*>(derived1);}
        base* base1;
        derived* derived1;
};
```

This is bad because it is not guaranteed to work by the C++ standard, and it will almost certainly not work if you use multiple/virtual inheritance. Use this only if `func` has to be as fast as possible (i.e. *inline*), and if you don't need your code to be portable.

Comment: I'll bear this in mind but use the other solution for now. It's usefull to know. I didn't realise that the reinterpret_cast could be used in this way.